# Running C Programs on Linux

Tags: command-line, executable, gcc, command-not-found

I watched a video lecture today that introduced C and things like how to make a C program that will run in Linux. I followed the steps given and now I'm stuck with a bit of a problem.

I created my C file (HelloWorld.c) and used the command `gcc -o HelloWorld HelloWorld.c` to compile the file, both of these steps were successful. Afterwards I checked to make sure that HelloWorld had been created by using the command `ls`, and it had been. However, when I use the command `HelloWorld`, which is supposed to run the program, I get an error that says `HelloWorld: command not found`.

In the video lecture the professor did mention that this worked for 32-bit systems and I'm using a 64-bit system. Perhaps this could be the problem?

EDIT: Also in the video lecture the professor mentioned that when I use the command `ls` I should see `HelloWorld*`. I see only HelloWorld (without the star).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have the value of the `PATH` environment variable set to include whatever directory the HelloWorld executable file lives in.

Supposing you have used `cd` to get to the directory, you can run HelloWorld with this command: `./HelloWorld`

Unix shells have a variable called `PATH`, which is a `:`-delimited list of directories in which to look when the user issues a command without a fully-qualified path name (`/usr/bin/ls` is fully qualified: it starts at `/` and ends at `ls`, but `ls` is not fully-qualified by itself).  If you don't have an entry of `.` in `PATH`, you have to explicitly use `./` on the beginning of a command to get the file of that name in the current directory to execute.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that '.' is not in PATH for security reasons, and therefore it is a bad idea to add it. In case anyone thinks this was some unaccountable oversight on the part of their OS provider.

Comment: How would you run the program with command-line arguments, then?

Comment: @AndersonGreen `./HelloWorld arg1 arg2 arg3 etc`

Comment: Regarding current directory of `.` being in `PATH`, for a **regular user** who falls under the security umbrella of the system it should no longer be said `it should not be done for security reasons`.  It is not 1995, and with most modern linux distros there are plenty of other functional security mechanisms in place preventing what used to be a risk regarding this.  Any user **has always been able** to modify PATH and put `.` anywhere in it.  This is one of those old ideas die hard; doing `.` in PATH for the root account would be a *risk* and should not be done unless the risk is understood

Answer (score 3):

Use `ls -F` to see a star at the end of filename.  If you use `ls` from GNU coreutils you can set the environment variable `LS_OPTIONS` to automatically include this and any other number of options for you.  The options for `ls` are listed in the `ls` manual, to see them run:  `man ls`

@brewer2:  setting environment variables on login is shell specific and a good question in itself.

Comment: How would I set LS_OPTIONS to automatically include -F?

Comment: While I think the accepted answer is the right one, this is also good to know.

Comment: @brewer2 `alias ls='ls -F'`